# retrieve JSON response of a POST request in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest

I am sending s POST request to a service and it is supposed to return a JSON in response. I see the POST is successful but I dont get anything in response back. What am I missing? Below code

```
var headers = {
    "Accept":"application/json",
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization": ("Basic " + new Buffer("admin:password").toString('base64'))

}




// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'myservice-url',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : headers
}


// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        var str = JSON.stringify(body, null, 2);
        console.log(str)

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, need to confirm if you have properly installed the following:

> https://github.com/request/request

Then require it in your file like this:

```
var request = require('request');

    request.post({
        url: "",//your url
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
        requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
        agent: false,//add when working with https sites
        form: {
            whateverfieldnameyouwant: "whatevervalueyouwant"
        }
    },function (response, err, body){
        console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Just edit, the headers according to your needs. but that is how I use it. In one of my node projects.

Comment: now I see the result but the format is not JSON. It breaks the JSON format.  Also my service doesn't support application/x-www-form-urlencoded' so I used 'Content-Type': 'application/json' and removed the section form: {
            whateverfieldnameyouwant: "whatevervalueyouwant"
        }

Comment: What is breaking the JSON format? if you are getting a string, you can try body.split(<delimiter>');

Comment: Oh, and your service, what language is it in? you may have to specify the header of you service, also, for it to be in json format.

Comment: the results are missing double quote (""). For example urgency: '3' should really be "urgency": "3"

Comment: your JSON output, from your service, prolly returned it without it, because its an INTEGER. But if you need it to be string, in nodejs side.you can parse it to string like this... body.urgency.toString();

Comment: Hope this helps. Please Upvote my answer and Accept it, if it does.. :)